# Combinations or Permutations of bits

Tags: permutations, combinations, binary

I am a computer science major and was explaining to someone how a computer uses bits to represent numbers.  If you have $1$ bit, you can have $0$ or $1$.  With $2$ bits, you can have $00, 01, 10, 11$ or $0, 1, 2, 3$ in decimal.  And so on, up to $32$ bits, where you can have about $4.2$ billion.... what?  Combinations or Permutations?

Comment: They are permutations (with repetition).

Answer (score 1):

For each bit, there are two options.

As you see, with two bits, there $2\cdot 2 = 2^2$ possible distinct strings.

With three bits, there are $2\cdot 2\cdot 2 = 2^3 = 8$ possible distinct strings.

$\quad \vdots$

Wit $32$ bits at our disposal, there are $2^{32}$ distinct strings that can be formed.

Comment: Yes, but are those 2^32 possible distinct strings combinations or permutations of some set of 0s and 1s?

I know how many distinct strings there are: 2^32 = ~4.2 billion.  My question is, are those distinct strings permutations or combinations of some set of 0s and 1s.

Comment: They are combinations where *order matters* (each bit in a string of bits occupies a "place" where the nth bit occupies the $(n - 1)$th place and clearly, with repetition of characters is allowed, indeed very meaningful). I prefer to  call them distinct "strings" since order matters and repetition is allowed. A permutation is the number of ways that distinct elements can be distinctly arranged. There are exactly two distinct permutations on the set $\{0, 1\}$.

Comment: Suppose the set has 64 elements: 32 0s and 32 1s.  And we are creating strings of 32 bits.  Is it correct to say that the strings are combinations and not permutations because e.g. (first)0 (second)0 is the same as (second)0 (first)0 so the latter is discarded?

Comment: Also, now I'm curious.  Would the permutations on the set {0,1} not be 0, 1, 01, and 10?

Comment: In a permutation, you have a set of elements, which is known, and the only question is : how many orders are possible with this set of elements. Permuting= ordering in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

### neither of the two, but states

Here's why? say we have **`4`** bits then the sum of configurations (states) from possible **`combinations`** for it would be $$\sum_{n=0}^4 4C_n $$ from $$ \sum_{n=0}^N NC_n  = 2^N $$
$$ where\,N = no.\,of\,bits  \\where\,n = no.\,of\,set\,bits\\and\,C = combination\,operator $$
$$i.e. 4C_0 + 4C_1 + 4C_2 + 4C_3 + 4C_4 = sum\,of\, the\,5\,possible\,combinations =  2^4  states $$
 as per the addition of $$4C_0[1]  = \begin{cases}
0000 
\end{cases} \\ \\ 4C_1[4]  = \begin{cases}
0001 \\
0010 \\
0100 \\
1000 \\
\end{cases} \\ 4C_2 [6] = \begin{cases}
0011 \\
0101 \\
0110 \\
1001 \\
1010 \\
1100 \\
\end{cases} \\ 4C_3 [4] = \begin{cases}
0111 \\
1011 \\
1101 \\
1110 \\
\end{cases}\\ 4C_4 [1] = \begin{cases}
1111
\end{cases} $$

to give 16 states in total

Answer (score 0):

Bit significance is based on permutations. If I had 001 & 100 and bit significance was based on combination, the previous two would be equal. However, since the order of the bits matter, the bits' significance is based on permutations.